# How to add hover effect to TListBoxItem?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

With other styles controls, I would normally add a background rectangle to a custom ListboxItem style and define a color animation with `Trigger: IsMouseOver=true`, but it does not work in this situation.

Only if I set `HitTest := True` for the background rectangle, then the hover animation works, but then the ListBox does not respond to clicks on the item, and you cannot select an item.

How do I add the hover effect to the ListBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem a while ago.
The only workaround i could find is to skip the style and create your own listboxitem. Only thing is your text will disappear, so i added a label to display the text. 
Its not the great, but it worked in my case

```
type
  TMouseOverListBoxItem = class(TListBoxItem)
  private
    FBackGround: TRectangle;
    FHoverAni: TColorAnimation;
    FLabel: TLabel;
    procedure BackgroundClicked(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure DoTextChanged; override;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
 end;


procedure TMouseOverListBoxItem.AfterConstruction;
const 
  cStart = TAlphaColorRec.White;
  cStop  = TAlphaColorRec.Yellow;
begin
  inherited;
  // Create background
  FBackGround := TRectangle.Create(Self);
  FBackGround.Parent := Self;
  FBackGround.Fill.Color := cStart;
  FBackGround.Align := TAlignLayout.Contents;
  FBackGround.HitTest := True;
  FBackGround.Sides := [];
  FBackGround.OnClick := BackgroundClicked;

  // Create mouse over animation
  FHoverAni := TColorAnimation.Create(FBackGround);
  FHoverAni.Parent := FBackGround;
  FHoverAni.Trigger := 'IsMouseOver=true';
  FHoverAni.TriggerInverse := 'IsMouseOver=false';
  FHoverAni.StartValue := cStart;
  FHoverAni.StopValue := cStop;
  FHoverAni.PropertyName := 'Fill.Color';

   // Create label to show text. Background will hide original text
  FLabel := TLabel.Create(FBackGround);
  FLabel.Parent := FBackGround;
  FLabel.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
end;

procedure TMouseOverListBoxItem.BackgroundClicked(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(OnClick) then
    OnClick(Self)
  else if Assigned(ListBox.OnItemClick) then
    ListBox.OnItemClick(ListBox, Self);
end;

procedure TMouseOverListBoxItem.DoTextChanged;
begin
  inherited;
  FLabel.Text := Self.Text;
end;
```